# Connecting SQL Server to Golang gorm

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, go, go-gorm

I am new in Golang btw. I got confused when I try to connect gorm to remote SQL Server database.

In .NET I usually use this for web.config

```
<add name="DevSaveLog" connectionString="Data Source=11.111.1.111;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Database_Log;User ID=user_log;Password=dhhdf127ihd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And when I try to connect to gorm I tried like this

```
func Init() {
dsn := url.QueryEscape("sqlserver://user_log:dhhdf127ihd@http://11.111.1.111?database=Database_Log")
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
if err != nil {
    panic("error connecting to database")
}
db.AutoMigrate()
```

}

And I got errors :

```
[error] failed to initialize database, got error unable to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433': dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1433: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

panic: error connecting to database

BTW I don't use the real URL in this question .Even I have declared the url server of sqlserver database it just keep reading localhost.

Any solutions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues ([the docs](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#SQL-Server) are a good place to start):

### DSN String

`sqlserver://user_log:dhhdf127ihd@http://11.111.1.111?database=Database_Log` is not a valid DSN (remove the `http://`).

### URL Encoding

`url.QueryEscape("sqlserver://user_log:dhhdf127ihd@http://11.111.1.111?database=Database_Log")` returns `sqlserver%3A%2F%2Fuser_log%3Adhhdf127ihd%40http%3A%2F%2F11.111.1.111%3Fdatabase%3DDatabase_Log`.

This is not a valid URL and will not be correctly processed by `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` which [looks for a prefix](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/1598eaf61e43a1bb1b66231abe49f8613b544d64/msdsn/conn_str.go#L120) of `sqlserver://`. Remove the `url.QueryEscape`.

In summary try something like:

```
dsn := "sqlserver://user_log:dhhdf127ihd@11.111.1.111?database=Database_Log"
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

Comment: Ok - just encode the password (see [this issue](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/602#issuecomment-694193470)).

Comment: wow it's work when I tried to escape the "fancy" password
dsn := "sqlserver://user_log:" + url.QueryEscape("xrhGzBL$i=F2T|r*") + "@11.111.1.111?database=Database_Log"
so many thanks